# autocomplete with search and append

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am trying autocomplete.js plugin. Currently it is giving me functionality of search and select. How Can I achieve search and append.

Example: If my dataset is ["one", "two", "three"] and I am typing 'one' and selecting it and then if am giving space it should show suggestion again and after select it should append both suggestion like 'one two' not one only.

github url: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/#jquery

Comment: Which plugin are you referring to?

Comment: autocomplete.js. githug url: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/#jquery

Comment: Doesn't look like the plugin supports multi select. Probably have to do it yourself

Comment: yes seems like. I tried multiple plugin and they are doing the same thing. Any plugin suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html) one seems to do what you want.

Comment: jquery-ui is not showing suggestion again if I am typing any text other than suggestion list.I am figuring out some other solution. Thank you for suggestion @H77

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with web application. Try the follwing codes.

Use in header tag. Or in a js file

```
 <script>

$( function() {

var availableTags = [

"ActionScript",

"AppleScript",

"Asp",

"BASIC",

"C",

"C++",

"Clojure",

"COBOL",

"ColdFusion",

"Erlang",

"Fortran",

"Groovy",

"Haskell",

"Java",

"JavaScript",

"Lisp",

"Perl",

"PHP",

"Python",

"Ruby",

"Scala",

"Scheme"

];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({

source: availableTags

});

} );

</script>
```

Use the following in body.

```
<div class="ui-widget">

<label for="tags">Tags: </label>

<input id="tags">

</div>
```